# Special characters in function in R

Tags: r, regex, extract

I am going to use a "used" code in a function. Here is the code

```
str_extract("temp", pattern = "(?:[^-]*\\-){1}([^\\-]*)$")))
```

Here is the "temp" variable value:

```
WV-Online-Reading-S1-COMBINED-ELA-3
```

Here is the extracted output after running this function:

```
ELA-3
```

Can someone please explain to me how those special characters in `"pattern = .."` works?

Using the same function, I would like to convert this:

```
AIR-GEN-SUM-UD-ELA-NH-COMBINED-3-SEG1
```

to this:

```
ELA-3
```

A good reference to those special characters would also be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: The string in the `pattern` argument is called a 'regular expression'. Have a look at this [Cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/strings.pdf), for example. On the second page the elements are explained one by one.

Comment: Worth nothing also that this regular expression is not related to the `mutate` function, but rather  is used by `str_extract` in the part like: `str_extract(x, pattern="(?:[^-]*\\-){1}([^\\-]*)$")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find the correct regular expression you need to know what exactly you are systematically looking for in your strings. From your post I assume that you want to extract the `ELA_` string and the number at the end of the strings. You could do it like this:

```
strings <- c("WV-Online-Reading-S1-COMBINED-ELA-3", "AIR-GEN-SUM-UD-ELA-NH-COMBINED-3-SEG1")

gsub(".*(ELA\\-).*(\\d$)", "\\1\\2", strings)

[1] "ELA-3" "ELA-1"
```

I will briefly explain the components of the pattern:

- `.*` matches zero or more arbitraty characters
- `ELA\\-` matches 'ELA-'
- `\\d$` matches a digit at the end of the line

The brackets form a capture group which can be "backreferenced" to by `\\1` (first capture group) and `\\2` (second capture group). `gsub()` takes the entire strings and replaces it by what it could match in both backreferences. As I do not know the exact systematic of what you are looking for the pattern might still need adjustments to fit your needs.

If you are interested in the first digit only you can get it with

```
library(stringr)
strings %>% str_extract("\\d")
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I made a typo, I actually wanted to have ELA-3 rather than ELA-1. So  I needed to extract the first digit.

Comment: So in this expression, "AIR-GEN-SUM-UD-ELA-NH-COMBINED-3-SEG1", I need to extract the first digit only.